# QTableView does not update the data

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qsqlquery, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm using a QTableView to view some data from sql database.
the structure is as follows :

1. QSqlQueryModel
2. subclass of QSortFilterProxyModel that's used to filter data through search box
3. QTableView and it's model is the proxy model.

Sometimes when I search and the FilterAcceptsRow is called, the view doesn't load the data, surprisingly when I resize the window or click on the header to sort it, the data gets loaded !

```
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row,
                                  const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    QModelIndex indName = sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               7, source_parent);
    QModelIndex indNumber= sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               6, source_parent);
    QModelIndex indAgency = sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               0, source_parent);

    QModelIndex indStartDate = sourceModel()->index(source_row,2,source_parent);
    QModelIndex indEndDate = sourceModel()->index(source_row,1,source_parent);
    if (searchBy == 0) // search by name
    {
        if(sourceModel()->data(indName).toString().contains(name_))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if( searchBy == 1)  // search by number
    {
        if(sourceModel()->data(indNumber).toString().toLower().contains(number_.toLower()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (searchBy == 2) // search by agency
    {
        return agencyList.indexOf(sourceModel()->data(indAgency).toString()) == agency_ ;
    }

    else if (searchBy == 3) // search By date
    {
        if (sourceModel()->data(indStartDate).toDate() >= start_ &&
               sourceModel()->data(indEndDate).toDate() <= end_)
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there someway to get this working properly ?

Comment: Do you call invalidateFilter() when the filter condition is changed?

Comment: I do, and it does update the model, however the view does not update
Btw, I'm working with Qt 5.9 on Ubuntu 16.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for that issue, It turns out that the QSortFilterProxyModel does not load all the data until you scroll the QTableView down, then it starts to load the rest of the data.
and that might be a good thing if there is a lot of data, so it's on by default.

I got it working the way i needed by using

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const
```

and

```
void QAbstractItemModel::fetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent)
```

after each call for `invalidateFilter();`

I call them to fetch all the data

```
while (canFetchMore(sourceModel()->index(rowCount()-1,0)))
{
    fetchMore(sourceModel()->index(rowCount()-1,0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working snippet from my project

```
#include "qqmlsortfilterproxymodel.h"
#include <QtQml>
#include <algorithm>
#include "filter.h"
#include "sorter.h"

QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::QQmlSortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
    connect(this, &QAbstractProxyModel::sourceModelChanged, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::updateRoles);
    connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::modelReset, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::updateRoles);
    connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::countChanged);
    connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsRemoved, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::countChanged);
    connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::modelReset, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::countChanged);
    connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::layoutChanged, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::countChanged);
    setDynamicSortFilter(true);
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::count() const
{
    return rowCount();
}

const QString& QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filterRoleName() const
{
    return m_filterRoleName;
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterRoleName(const QString& filterRoleName)
{
    if (m_filterRoleName == filterRoleName)
        return;

    m_filterRoleName = filterRoleName;
    updateFilterRole();
    Q_EMIT filterRoleNameChanged();
}

QString QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filterPattern() const
{
    return filterRegExp().pattern();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterPattern(const QString& filterPattern)
{
    QRegExp regExp = filterRegExp();
    if (regExp.pattern() == filterPattern)
        return;

    regExp.setPattern(filterPattern);
    QSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(regExp);
    Q_EMIT filterPatternChanged();
}

QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::PatternSyntax QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filterPatternSyntax() const
{
    return static_cast<PatternSyntax>(filterRegExp().patternSyntax());
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterPatternSyntax(QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::PatternSyntax patternSyntax)
{
    QRegExp regExp = filterRegExp();
    QRegExp::PatternSyntax patternSyntaxTmp = static_cast<QRegExp::PatternSyntax>(patternSyntax);
    if (regExp.patternSyntax() == patternSyntaxTmp)
        return;

    regExp.setPatternSyntax(patternSyntaxTmp);
    QSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterRegExp(regExp);
    Q_EMIT filterPatternSyntaxChanged();
}

const QVariant& QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filterValue() const
{
    return m_filterValue;
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setFilterValue(const QVariant& filterValue)
{
    if (m_filterValue == filterValue)
        return;

    m_filterValue = filterValue;
    invalidateFilter();
    Q_EMIT filterValueChanged();
}

const QString& QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::sortRoleName() const
{
    return m_sortRoleName;
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setSortRoleName(const QString& sortRoleName)
{
    if (m_sortRoleName == sortRoleName)
        return;

    m_sortRoleName = sortRoleName;
    updateSortRole();
    Q_EMIT sortRoleNameChanged();
}

bool QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::ascendingSortOrder() const
{
    return m_ascendingSortOrder;
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::setAscendingSortOrder(bool ascendingSortOrder)
{
    if (m_ascendingSortOrder == ascendingSortOrder)
        return;

    m_ascendingSortOrder = ascendingSortOrder;
    Q_EMIT ascendingSortOrderChanged();
    invalidate();
}

QQmlListProperty<Filter> QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filters()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<Filter>(this, &m_filters,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::append_filter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::count_filter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::at_filter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::clear_filters);
}

QQmlListProperty<Sorter> QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::sorters()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<Sorter>(this, &m_sorters,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::append_sorter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::count_sorter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::at_sorter,
                                    &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::clear_sorters);
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::classBegin()
{

}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::componentComplete()
{
    m_completed = true;
    for (const auto& filter : m_filters)
        filter->proxyModelCompleted();
    invalidate();
    sort(0);
}
QVariant QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::sourceData(const QModelIndex& sourceIndex, const QString& roleName) const
{
    int role = sourceModel()->roleNames().key(roleName.toUtf8());
    return sourceData(sourceIndex, role);
}

QVariant QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::sourceData(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex, int role) const
{
    return sourceModel()->data(sourceIndex, role);
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::roleForName(const QString& roleName) const
{
    return roleNames().key(roleName.toUtf8(), -1);
}

QVariantMap QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::get(int row) const
{
    QVariantMap map;
    QModelIndex modelIndex = index(row, 0);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = roleNames();
    for (QHash<int, QByteArray>::const_iterator it = roles.begin(); it != roles.end(); ++it)
       map.insert(it.value(), data(modelIndex, it.key()));

    return map;
}

QVariant QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::get(int row, const QString& roleName) const
{
    return data(index(row, 0), roleForName(roleName));
}

QModelIndex QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const
{
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource(proxyIndex);
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::mapToSource(int proxyRow) const
{
    QModelIndex proxyIndex = index(proxyRow, 0);
    QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource(proxyIndex);
    return sourceIndex.isValid() ? sourceIndex.row() : -1;
}

QModelIndex QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex& sourceIndex) const
{
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::mapFromSource(sourceIndex);
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::mapFromSource(int sourceRow) const
{
    QModelIndex proxyIndex;
    if (QAbstractItemModel* source = sourceModel()) {
        QModelIndex sourceIndex = source->index(sourceRow, 0);
        proxyIndex = mapFromSource(sourceIndex);
    }
    return proxyIndex.isValid() ? proxyIndex.row() : -1;
}

bool QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const
{
    if (!m_completed)
        return true;
    QModelIndex sourceIndex = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);
    bool valueAccepted = !m_filterValue.isValid() || ( m_filterValue == sourceModel()->data(sourceIndex, filterRole()) );
    bool baseAcceptsRow = valueAccepted && QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
    baseAcceptsRow = baseAcceptsRow && std::all_of(m_filters.begin(), m_filters.end(),
        [=, &source_parent] (Filter* filter) {
            return filter->filterAcceptsRow(sourceIndex);
        }
    );
    return baseAcceptsRow;
}

bool QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex& source_left, const QModelIndex& source_right) const
{
    if (m_completed) {
        if (!m_sortRoleName.isEmpty()) {
            if (QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(source_left, source_right))
                return m_ascendingSortOrder;
            if (QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(source_right, source_left))
                return !m_ascendingSortOrder;
        }
        for(auto sorter : m_sorters) {
            if (sorter->enabled()) {
                int comparison = sorter->compareRows(source_left, source_right);
                if (comparison != 0)
                    return comparison < 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return source_left.row() < source_right.row();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::resetInternalData()
{
    QSortFilterProxyModel::resetInternalData();
    if (sourceModel() && QSortFilterProxyModel::roleNames().isEmpty()) { // workaround for when a model has no roles and roles are added when the model is populated (ListModel)
        // QTBUG-57971
        connect(sourceModel(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::initRoles);
        connect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsAboutToBeInserted, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::initRoles);
    }
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter()
{
    if (m_completed)
        QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate()
{
    if (m_completed)
        QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::updateFilterRole()
{
    QList<int> filterRoles = roleNames().keys(m_filterRoleName.toUtf8());
    if (!filterRoles.empty())
    {
        setFilterRole(filterRoles.first());
    }
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::updateSortRole()
{
    QList<int> sortRoles = roleNames().keys(m_sortRoleName.toUtf8());
    if (!sortRoles.empty())
    {
        setSortRole(sortRoles.first());
        invalidate();
    }
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::updateRoles()
{
    updateFilterRole();
    updateSortRole();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::initRoles()
{
    disconnect(sourceModel(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted, this, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::initRoles);
    disconnect(this, &QAbstractItemModel::rowsAboutToBeInserted, this , &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::initRoles);
    resetInternalData();
    updateRoles();
}

QVariantMap QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::modelDataMap(const QModelIndex& modelIndex) const
{
    QVariantMap map;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = roleNames();
    for (QHash<int, QByteArray>::const_iterator it = roles.begin(); it != roles.end(); ++it)
        map.insert(it.value(), sourceModel()->data(modelIndex, it.key()));
    return map;
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::append_filter(QQmlListProperty<Filter>* list, Filter* filter)
{
    if (!filter)
        return;

    QQmlSortFilterProxyModel* that = static_cast<QQmlSortFilterProxyModel*>(list->object);
    that->m_filters.append(filter);
    connect(filter, &Filter::invalidate, that, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter);
    filter->m_proxyModel = that;
    that->invalidateFilter();
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::count_filter(QQmlListProperty<Filter>* list)
{
    QList<Filter*>* filters = static_cast<QList<Filter*>*>(list->data);
    return filters->count();
}

Filter* QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::at_filter(QQmlListProperty<Filter>* list, int index)
{
    QList<Filter*>* filters = static_cast<QList<Filter*>*>(list->data);
    return filters->at(index);
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::clear_filters(QQmlListProperty<Filter> *list)
{
    QQmlSortFilterProxyModel* that = static_cast<QQmlSortFilterProxyModel*>(list->object);
    that->m_filters.clear();
    that->invalidateFilter();
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::append_sorter(QQmlListProperty<Sorter>* list, Sorter* sorter)
{
    if (!sorter)
        return;

    auto that = static_cast<QQmlSortFilterProxyModel*>(list->object);
    that->m_sorters.append(sorter);
    connect(sorter, &Sorter::invalidate, that, &QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate);
    sorter->m_proxyModel = that;
    that->invalidate();
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::count_sorter(QQmlListProperty<Sorter>* list)
{
    auto sorters = static_cast<QList<Sorter*>*>(list->data);
    return sorters->count();
}

Sorter* QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::at_sorter(QQmlListProperty<Sorter>* list, int index)
{
    auto sorters = static_cast<QList<Sorter*>*>(list->data);
    return sorters->at(index);
}

void QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::clear_sorters(QQmlListProperty<Sorter>* list)
{
    auto that = static_cast<QQmlSortFilterProxyModel*>(list->object);
    that->m_sorters.clear();
    that->invalidate();
}

int QQmlSortFilterProxyModel::getRowCount() const
{
   return rowCount();
}

void registerQQmlSortFilterProxyModelTypes() {
    qmlRegisterType<QQmlSortFilterProxyModel>("SortFilterProxyModel", 0, 2, "SortFilterProxyModel");
}

Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION(registerQQmlSortFilterProxyModelTypes)
```